# Hold button -> repeat function

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to achieve something which souldn't be hard to do, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.

I have a function that changes a value every time I click a button, and what I want is: when I hold this button, the value should keep changing.

This is what I've tried and hasn't worked, setInterval and setTimeout won't "wait" (the function get's called right away thousands of times and the website crashes):

```
    $('.buttonPlus').mousedown(function() {
        timeoutID =setTimeout(distribucionPorcentual($(this)),1000);
    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    });
```

Any help will be greately appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted here isn't syntactically valid -- the semicolon in `1000;)` is illegal and your alternative code sample has mismatched parentheses. Could you create an example that verifiably reproduces your problem and copy it directly here?

Comment: My bad, I tried translating the code and messed up a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was a jumbled mess of mistakes (one misplaced semicolon, two missing brackets etc). On any modern browser, JS would've prevented the events from binding - were you testing on IE?

IF you were, here is a corrected version: http://tinker.io/fd2da . I've also fixed a little problem of scope in the `setTimeout` call (`this` is null in a setTimeout closure call).

the code:

```
 // stub the calls
 function distribucionPorcentual(arg) {
 }
 function distribution(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.buttonPlus').mousedown(function() {
    console.log("Test");
        distribucionPorcentual($(this));
    var t = $(this);
       timeoutID =setTimeout(function() {distribution(t); },1000);
    }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    console.log("Mouseup");
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    });
 });
```

You may want to bind the mouseup/mouseleave inside the setTimeout to save yourself from having to have to deal with a global variable.

Comment: @Waclock: do you want to call it once/second? If so, change all `setTimeout` to `setInterval` and `clearTimeout` to `clearInterval`.

Comment: Thanks! I could swear I had tried that last night, but didn't work. Now it did! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, but if someone stumbles upon it (I just did), you might find this useful. I needed to be able to do a simple increment, but if the mouse is held for a full second, then it goes into a rapid increment. Which is similar to how a keypress behaves on many systems.

```
    $('#forward-step').mousedown(function() {
    adjustPosition(1)
    var cancel = false;
    repeatDelayTimer = setTimeout( function() {
        if (!cancel) {
            repeatTimer = setInterval(function() {adjustPosition(1); },50);
        }
    },1000 )
    
    t.bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        cancel = true;
        console.log("Mouseup");
        clearInterval(repeatTimer);
        clearTimeout(repeatDelayTimer);
    });
});
```